# How to take an item out of a list box and another item in a different list box in the same position

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listbox, listboxitems

I am trying yo create a method that will take a value of one list box and will also be taken out of another list box at the same index. I am just a beginner to C# which is why I am having this problem. Thanks in advance for any help

```
if (lstCheckoutProduct.)
                {
                    lstCheckoutProduct.Items.Remove(lstCheckoutProduct.SelectedItem);
                    int productIndex = lstCheckoutProduct.Items.IndexOf(lstCheckoutProduct.SelectedIndex);
                    lstCheckoutPrice.Items.Remove(productIndex);
                }
                else
                {
                    lstCheckoutPrice.Items.Remove(lstCheckoutPrice.SelectedItem);
                    int priceIndex = lstCheckoutPrice.Items.IndexOf(lstCheckoutPrice.SelectedIndex);
                    lstCheckoutPrice.Items.Remove(priceIndex);
                }
```

Comment: Should your first if statement be checking if there is a selected item? It just ends in a dot

Comment: `lstCheckoutPrice.Items.IndexOf(lstCheckoutPrice.SelectedIndex)` Why?

Comment: Also in your else I think you should be removing from lstCheckoutProduct.items instead of lstCheckoutPrice.items

Comment: I used selected index as I thought if I get the position of a product then the price will be in the same index just on a different listbox, so therefore I could find it

Comment: @M.Walker, you don't need to try doing both `IndexOf` and `SelectedIndex`. `SelectedIndex` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the SelectedIndex **before** removing the items. Also I assume your first line should check if the listbox is focused

And if you want to remove an item at a specific index you need to use [RemoveAt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
if (lstCheckoutProduct.IsFocused)
{
  int productIndex = lstCheckoutProduct.SelectedIndex;
  lstCheckoutProduct.Items.Remove(lstCheckoutProduct.SelectedItem);
  lstCheckoutPrice.Items.RemoveAt(productIndex);
}
else
{
  int priceIndex = lstCheckoutPrice.SelectedIndex;
  lstCheckoutPrice.Items.Remove(lstCheckoutPrice.SelectedItem);
  lstCheckoutProduct.Items.RemoveAt(priceIndex);
}
```

EDIT: The first line is just a guess as you left it out in your question. Note that `IsFocused` will be `false` if the user has clicked a "Remove"-button (and thereby focussed the button instead of the listbox) to call this method.

EDIT: and you can reduce the code to this:

```
int index = lstCheckoutProduct.IsFocused ? lstCheckoutProduct.SelectedIndex : lstCheckoutPrice.SelectedIndex;
lstCheckoutProduct.Items.RemoveAt(index);
lstCheckoutPrice.Items.RemoveAt(index);
```